# replace all key with minus to underscore in json

Tags: python, json

I have a json file (in fact, more than hundreds). Sometimes some keys have a dash in them.

```json
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "xxxxxxxx-1395-088e-2704-07359f399de5",
  "detail-type": "test",
  "source": "aws",
  ...
}
```

My purpose is, looking for any keys (sometimes it is nested key), find it out and replace any minus to underscore.

I can replace one key with Python code, but how can search out all keys if they have minus in key string?

the output will be

```json
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "xxxxxxxx-1395-088e-2704-07359f399de5",
  "detail_type": "test",
  "source": "aws",
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you add the desired output?

Comment: updated, the output in this sample, it has only one key `detail-key`, find it out and replace to `detail_key`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
file_content = {
  "version": "0",
  "id": "xxxxxxxx-1395-088e-2704-07359f399de5",
  "detail-type": "test",
  "source": "aws"
}
for key in list(file_content.keys()):
    if not isinstance(key, str):
        continue
    value = file_content[key]
    del file_content[key]
    file_content[key.replace("-","_")] = value

print(file_content)
```

json reading and writing can be done using the json module's functions [load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) and [dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump).

Comment: Looks promise, let me test